# Screen brightness on Macbook Air June 2012 running Windows 7 Pro x64

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, display

Adjusting the screen brightness on my Macbook Air (June 2012) isn't working in Windows 7 Pro x64.

I saw some comments online saying there's a regedit I can do to enable brightness, but that didn't work because this model doesn't use nVidia, it has an intel HD 4000 graphics chip as far as I know...

I tried to install the HD 4000 driver from intel but now my laptop just boots to a black screen, but I'm confident I can fix that issue when I get home.

I'm wondering if anyone here is successfully running win7x64 on their June 2012 macbook air's? So far only the screen brightness is an issue albeit a pretty annoying one for a laptop. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 64x support is terrible for this macbook air. If anyone else runs into this issue be ready to either struggle with power and display issues daily or just go to windows 7 x86. I dealt with the problems for about a month before switching, I'm much happier now.